# Pass globally installed package from step to step

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm-install, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a CDK codepipeline, which, simplified, looks something like this:

```
    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
      synth: new CodeBuildStep('InstallStep', {
        commands: ['npm install -g some-package'],
      }),
    });
    
    const initStep = new CodeBuildStep(`InitStep`, {
      commands: ['some-package']
    })
```

An NPM package is installed globally during synth step. Is there a way to use it in other build steps without reinstalling it again? I know I can easily pass build artifacts betwen the steps, but not sure about globally installed things.

Answer (score 0):

Considering each code build step is a new compute instance, I don't *think* you can cache global node_modules. You may be able to instead do something like

```
    const initStep = new CodeBuildStep(`InitStep`, {
      commands: ['npx some-package']
    })
```

Using npx to call the package avoids having to have the extra install step, assuming you call it like a cli command.